# Update all rows in a column to new value

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

Apologies, I am sure this has been asked plenty of times but I have searched around for a good example and haven't been able to find one.

I'd like to run a method to insert a value into a particular column for all rows in a table. To give you an idea of the methods and queries I'm working with, this is my working update method for my Students table:

```
public void updateStudent(long id,String name, String age, String points,
        String teachernote,byte[] blob) {
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(Students.STUDENT_NAME, name);
    cv.put(Students.STUDENT_AGE, age);
    cv.put(Students.STUDENT_POINTS, points);
    cv.put(Students.TEACHERNOTE, teachernote);
    cv.put(Students.IMAGE,blob);

    db = sqlHp.getWritableDatabase();
    db.update(Students.TABLE, cv, Students.STUDENT_ID+"="+ id, null);
    db.close();
}
```

I'm after a query to update STUDENT_POINTS for all rows. Any help would be much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: did you try to update it without the where clause?

Comment: this isn't the method I've tried to use - sorry, I should have made that clear. I added it because I assumed it could be adapted. Are you suggesting to remove "Students.STUDENT_ID+"="+ id" and put null instead?

Comment: yes I am. Have you tried without removiing it?

Comment: I'll adapt it and give it a go

Comment: It worked! Thank you ever so much! I'll go ahead and tick solve if you're up to plopping the solution in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to update all rows you have to remove the `where` clause. In your example you should remove `Students.STUDENT_ID+"="+ id`, from  `db.update(Students.TABLE, cv, Students.STUDENT_ID+"="+ id, null);`